# Why is my Swift behaving slower than my Python?

Tags: python, swift

I wanted to answer the question:
**What 3 numbers, when multiplied together equal their sum?**
i.e.
a+b+c=a*b*c

I wrote this code in both Swift and Python, and I am getting a longer runtime in Swift, even after compiling. Every time there is a hit, it appends the product/sum to a list. Before showing a succesful result, it checks whether this already exists in the list (to avoid repeats). I know this is not optimal, I don't care, I would just like to know why Swift is slower than Python on this one. Here is the swift code:

```swift
var answers:[Int]=[]
for i in 1...1000{
    print(i)
    for j in 1...1000{
        for k in 1...1000{
            let a=i+j+k
            let b=i*j*k
            if a==b && !answers.contains(a) {
                print(i,j,k,"answer: ",a)
                answers.append(a)
            }
        }
    }
}

print(answers)
```

and here is the Python code:

```py
ans=[]
for i in range(1,1000):
    print(i)
    for j in range(1,1000):
        for k in range(1,1000):
            a=i+j+k
            b=i*j*k
            if a==b and a not in ans:
                print(i,j,k,"answer: ",a)
                ans.append(a)
```

When I do it up to 100, including print statements, Python takes **14** seconds, Swift takes **20** seconds.

Is there any fundamental difference between the codes, and why is Swift slower than Python?

Comment: Did you run it in release mode?

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: removing printing if you want to profile the relevant parts.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok what do you mean?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I kept the print statements so I know where I am in the loop, so I can time it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga even without the print statements, Swift is slower

Comment: Your Swift code runs in less than a second. – You did not by any chance try this in a Playground?

Comment: @MartinR no, it's in Terminal. For swift, I even compiled with swiftc

Comment: @MartinR, are you sure it runs in less than a second? I am running M1 MB Pro, Monterey. Because for me it's like 5 minutes

Comment: Did you select the “Release” configuration, so that the code is optimized?

Comment: What timings *do* you get? Are we talking "almost equal"? Are we talking "off by factor 2"? Or is it even "off by an order of magnitude"? How did you build/execute these?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi when I do it up to 100, including print statements, Python takes 14 seconds, Swift takes 20 seconds

Comment: @MartinR how do you select the Release configuration?

Comment: Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme ..., or Command-<.

Comment: So what timings you get for swift and Python?

Comment: @MartinR I didn't use XCode or a Playground for that, just a .swift file that I run from the terminal...

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok When I do it up to 100, including print statements, Python takes 14 seconds, Swift takes 20 seconds

Comment: @CezarProdan Add -O3 to your command line

Comment: @newswiftuser you mean to run ``` swift file.swift -O3``` ?

Comment: Compile the file with `swiftc -O prog.swift` and then run the compiled binary with `./prog`

Comment: @MartinR oh wow, that ran in a second.... I must've compiled wrong. I was writing `swiftc prog.swift -o` ... what's the difference? Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest to run `swiftc --help` and inspect the various options. `-O` is "Compile with optimizations“ and `-o <file>` is “Write output to <file>”

Answer (score 2):

I was compiling without optimisation.

Comment: Note that printing to the console is REALLY slow. For both Swift and Python that is likely to be the slowest thing in your program. Have it print every 1000 iterations, say, and when it is all done. If you want to compare performance, get rid of your print statements, capture the Date when you begin, then compute the elapsed time once you have completed all of your code by getting the Date once you have completed it and subtracting the two.